# Access or show item of nested json array in template in Angular 5

Tags: html, angular, ionic3

How can I show value of `line_donation` from `meta_data` array of this json data in my template?

Below is the json data coming from ngFor

```js
  "line_items": [
        {
            "id": 1003,
            "name": "Fresh Mango- 1 kg",
            "product_id": 218,
            "variation_id": 0,
            "quantity": 1,
            "tax_class": "",
            "subtotal": "36.00",
            "subtotal_tax": "7.20",
            "total": "36.00",
            "total_tax": "7.20",
            "taxes": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "total": "7.2",
                    "subtotal": "7.2"
                }
            ],
            "meta_data": [
                {
                    "id": 8873,
                    "key": "line_donation",
                    "value": "0"
                }
            ],
            "sku": "",
            "price": 36
        },
```

**order-summary.html**

```html
 <div class="order-details">
            <ion-item no-lines>
                <ion-label class="side-header">{{"Order Details" | translate}} </ion-label>
            </ion-item>
            <div *ngFor="let item of orderSummary.line_items | keys">
                <ion-row>
                    <ion-col width-75>
                        <ion-label no-margin>{{item.value.name}} - ({{item.value.quantity}}) </ion-label>

                   <div *ngFor="let data of orderSummary.meta_data | keys">
                        <p> {{"Donation" | translate}}: {{1*data.meta_data.value | currency:values.currency:symbol:'1.2-2'}} </p>
              
                    </ion-col>
                    <ion-col width-25 text-right>
                        <ion-label no-margin>{{1*item.value.subtotal | currency:values.currency:symbol:'1.2-2' }} </ion-label>
                    </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
            </div>
```

I want to access the value from `meta_data` array nested in `line_items`.I am not able how to get the value of `line_donation`.

Answer (score 0):

Access with line_items local property i.e. **item**

```
<div class="order-details">
    <ion-item no-lines>
        <ion-label class="side-header">{{"Order Details" | translate}} </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
    <div *ngFor="let item of orderSummary.line_items | keys">
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col width-75>
                <ion-label no-margin>{{item.value.name}} - ({{item.value.quantity}}) </ion-label>

                <div *ngFor="let data of item.meta_data | keys">
                    <p> {{"Donation" | translate}}: {{1*data.value | currency:values.currency:symbol:'1.2-2'}} </p>

            </ion-col>
            <ion-col width-25 text-right>
                <ion-label no-margin>{{1*item.value.subtotal | currency:values.currency:symbol:'1.2-2' }} </ion-label>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not working. Kindly check the response.I don't know how to access array inside nested object array.

Answer (score 0):

You can access this using `line_items[0].meta_data[0].value;`

If you want to access this with a proper condition.

```
if(line_items[0].meta_data[0]){
   line_items[0].meta_data[0].value;
}
```

**To access in Templates**

```
 <div class="order-details">
            <ion-item no-lines>
                <ion-label class="side-header">{{"Order Details" | translate}} </ion-label>
            </ion-item>
            <div *ngFor="let item of orderSummary.line_items">
                <ion-row>
                    <ion-col width-75>
                        <ion-label no-margin>{{item.value.name}} - ({{item.value.quantity}}) </ion-label>

                   <div *ngFor="let data of orderSummary.meta_data">
                        <p> {{"Donation" | translate}}: {{data.value | currency:values.currency:symbol:'1.2-2'}} </p>

                    </ion-col>
                    <ion-col width-25 text-right>
                        <ion-label no-margin>{{1*item.value.subtotal | currency:values.currency:symbol:'1.2-2' }} </ion-label>
                    </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
            </div>
```

Comment: Not working ! Kindly check in which pattern response is coming.i mean array nested in line_items array object.